# Comparing MD5s in Python

Tags: python, md5

For a programming exercise I designed for myself, and for use in a pretty non-secure system later on, I'm trying to compare MD5 hashes. The one that is stored in a plain text file and is pulled out by the `check_pw()` function and the one that is created from the submitted password from a CGI form. `md5_pw(`) is used to create all the hashes in the program.

For some reason, *if `(pair[1] == md5_pw(pw))`* **always fails**, even though my program prints out identical hashes in my error checking lines:

> ```
>     print "this is the pw from the file: ", pair[1], "<br />"
>     print "this is the md5 pw you entered: ", md5_pw(pw), "<br />"
> ```

*Where am I messing up?*

Code:

```
def md5_pw(pw):
    """Returns the MD5 hex digest of the pw with addition."""
    m = md5.new()
    m.update("4hJ2Yq7qdHd9sdjFASh9"+pw)
    return m.hexdigest()

def check_pw(user, pw, pwfile):
    """Returns True if the username and password match, False otherwise. pwfile is a xxx.txt format."""
    f = open(pwfile)
    for line in f:
        pair = line.split(":")
        print "this is the pw from the file: ", pair[1], "<br />"
        print "this is the md5 pw you entered: ", md5_pw(pw), "<br />"
        if (pair[0] == user):
            print "user matched <br />"
            if (pair[1] == md5_pw(pw)):
                f.close()
                return True
            else:
                f.close()
                print "passmatch a failure"
                return False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `pair[1]` probably has a trailing newline. Try:

```
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    pair = line.split(":")
    # ...etc
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was unaware of the fact that the iterator would return the newline as well... ah, Python!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that there's an problem with the file loading/parsing, most likely caused by a newline character. By paring your code down, I was able to find that your logic was sound:

```
def md5_pw(pw):
    m = md5.new()
    m.update("4hJ2Yq7qdHd9sdjFASh9"+pw)
    return m.hexdigest()

def check_pw(pw):
    pair = ("c317db7d54073ef5d345d6dd8b2c51e6")
    if (pair == md5_pw(pw)):
        return True
    else:
        return False

>>> import md5
>>> check_pw('fakepw')
False
>>> check_pw('testpw')
True
```

("c317db7d54073ef5d345d6dd8b2c51e6" is the md5 hash for "4hJ2Yq7qdHd9sdjFASh9testpw")